# Adding <div> Automatically To <table> In Wordpress Using Filter Referencing?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, regex

Does anyone know how I would automatically add `<div class="table-responsive">` before every instance of a `<table>` on a WordPress site using filter referencing?  I would also need to add a `</div>` to every instance of `</table>` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter `the_content` and use `preg_replace()` to look for instances of `<table></table>` and then surround them with your `<div>`.

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'wpse_260756_the_content', 10, 1 );
function wpse_260756_the_content( $content ) {
  $pattern = "/<table(.*?)>(.*?)<\/table>/i";
  $replacement = '<div class="table-responsive"><table$1>$2</table></div>';

  return preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this code to my functions.php file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Is the `<table>` part of the page, post, or custom post type? If it's not, then `the_content` filter won't work. If you're using a shortcode to display the table, then you may need to change the priority (10) to a higher number link 9999.

Comment: The `<table>` elements are on various pages, and are not using any shortcodes.

Comment: Are you adding the tables using the post editor?

Comment: Yes that is how the tables are being added.  The reason I need this to work is because I have users that are not tech savvy who just need to be able to use the table generator and have it work correctly on mobile devices automatically.

Comment: It might be easier to change your CSS/JS to recognize `<table>` instead of `<div class="table-responsive">`. If you namespace your body_class you can get higher levels of specificity and hopefully target what's needed, without a need to adjust user-generated markup.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? Make sure to enable jQuery before execute it.

```
<?php add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_js_to_wp_footer' );
function add_js_to_wp_footer(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('table').wrap('<div class="table-responsive"></div>');
})
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is working but the JQuery should be in this format: 
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
  $('table').wrap('<div class="table-responsive"></div>');
});

Comment: @zod Why is that? Using `jQuery` instead of `$` is often not necessary and various versions, including yours, of `.ready()` has been deprecated since 2016. The syntax used in the answer is the preferred syntax.

Comment: @hungerstar Because he is adding loose javascript code in the footer, and in WordPress you must use jQuery instead of $ to avoid initialization errors. Eventually you don't work with WordPress, I do, and I know to always wrap jQuery scripts like that, else you get errors in console, and this apply even today.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want this type of behavior to set a horizontal scroll onto the table.

If that was the case then here's what you can do.

```
<div class="w-[200px] overflow-hidden">
  <!-- 
    # Hack: Apply styles directly on the table.

    .table {
      display: block;
      overflow: auto;
    }
   -->
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>+xx xxxxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>+xx xxxxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>+xx xxxxxxxxxx</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That might work for adding the styles but I think OP also wants to automatically add the containing divs.